# SUDS client.service. issue

Tags: python, suds

I am utterly lost at what should be an easy task.

I am trying to use Python with SUDS to grab a WSDL URL, create client objects, modify some information, and then post back up the WSDL (Or where ever it tell me to post it).

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test.py", line 47, in <module>
    email_sent = client.service.sendEmail(From, SenderContext, Email)
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

If I remove the "Try:" section in the code and insert come print code to print the objects, everything works just fine. It does grab the information and do the changes I want.

What I don't understand is that the client object is created and I am trying to post the information back up, but can't. Any one have any experience with XML and Python?

```
import sys

import logging
import traceback as tb
import suds.metrics as metrics
import unittest
from suds import null, WebFault
from suds.client import Client

def sendTestMail():
    url = 'wsdl url at my company'
    client = Client(url)

    SenderContext = client.factory.create('senderContext')
    SenderContext.registeredSenderId = 'Endurance'
    SenderContext.mailType = 'TRANSACTIONAL_OTHER'
    SenderContext.subSenderId = 12345

    From = client.factory.create('emailAddressBean')
    From.address = 'me@somecompany.com'
    From.valid = 'TRUE'

    Email = client.factory.create('email')
    Email.recipients = 'me@somecompany.com'
    Email.ccRecipients = ''
    Email.bccRecipients = ''
    Email.agencyId = ''
    Email.content = 'This is a test of sending'
    Email.contentType = 'text/plain'
    Email.description = ''
    #Email.from = From
    Email.fromName = 'An Employee'
    Email.subject = 'This is a test'
    Email.mrrId = ''
    Email.templateId = ''

try:
    email_sent = client.service.sendEmail(From, SenderContext, Email)
except WebFault, e:
    print e

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    errors = 0
    sendTestMail()
    print '\nFinished: errors=%d' % errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You define **client** in the `sendTestMail()` class, but then use a lower-level indentation in your try/except statement. Therefore, client is not within scope at this point. Either indent your try/except block to be within the `sendTestMail()` scope or declare **client** globally.